# I'm generating a list from an array how can I know what element I'm clicking?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I started learning JavaScript a few weeks ago.
So basically I'm trying to make a little app for myself for my workplace.
The goal would be to list the actual month's days as buttons and every time I cliek one of these buttons, a Modal shows up where I can give it 3 options and the button will be colorized accordingly.
For example I want to be the normal working days to be green, when I'm on holiday they will be other color and when I'm sick they will show another color too.

But I can't seem to figure out how to tell JavaScript which button I'm clicking. I'm not ready with IndexedDB yet, but later I'm planning to use it to store data.
Here is my code which is a complete mess I'm 100% sure, but as I mentioned in the beginning, I just started learning and I'm happy whenever something works. Writing readable and nice code is my future plan.

Probably this is not the best way to do this either but this is all by myself and I tried this to challenge myself.

```
...
<ul id="days"></ul>
...
```

```
let today = now.getDate();
let currentMonth = now.getMonth()+1; 
let days = [01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
document.getElementById('currentMonth').textContent = monthName(currentMonth);
let holiday = document.querySelector('#holiday');
let weekend = document.querySelector('#weekend');
let sick = document.querySelector('#sick');



let dayList = document.querySelector('#days');
let fragment = new DocumentFragment();

days.forEach(function(day) {
    let days = document.createElement('button');
    days.innerHTML = day
    fragment.appendChild(days)
  days.setAttribute('data-toggle','modal');
    days.setAttribute('data-target', '#exampleModal');
    days.setAttribute('class', 'btn')
    if(day === today){
    days.setAttribute('class','btn btn-info');
    } else if (day < today) {
    days.setAttribute('class','btn btn-success');

    }
})

dayList.appendChild(fragment)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let btn

for(let i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  btn = document.createElement('button')
  btn.innerHTML = i+1
  btn.dataset.day = i+1
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.clear()
    console.log('Day ' + e.target.dataset.day + ' clicked')
  })
}
```

Comment: Wow... this is probably working but I'm way too beginner to undersand this :D 
For example what is the  
  
btn.innerHTML = i+1  
btn.dataset.day = i+1  
  
Also what is this part doing? function(e)?  
  
  
function(e)  
  
  
According to this answer, I'm better off deleting most of my JS part and redo it again like your reply

Comment: `btn.innerHTML = i+1` is what adds the numbers you see inside the buttons. `btn.dataset.day = i+1` adds the same number to the "data attribute" for the button, so the program can retrieve it later. `function(e)` is the callback function passed to `addEventListener()` that determines what happens when a `btn` element is clicked. The `e` is the event itself. `e.target` is the `btn` element (notice that's how I'm retrieving the data attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem by get the innerText of the buttons and put it into a variable. Therefore you can compare this variable name and find out which button you pressed.

I hope I could help. Good luck.

HTML

```
<button  onclick="GetValue(this)">Sick</button>
<button  onclick="GetValue(this)">Holiday</button>
<button  onclick="GetValue(this)">Weekend</button>
```

JS

```
function GetValue(e){
var buttonText=e.innerText;
console.log(buttonText)
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry maybe I was not clear. When I click one of the days for example I was on holiday today at work, so I would set the 28th of August to "Holiday", but all the buttons are the same hence I think JS don't know what I talk about when I click on of them.